# Laravel model save exception (nesting level...)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have table for like system(like, dislike);
I want insert or update new row, but on save() method i catch exception:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '250' reached, aborting!
```

There is code:

```
$liking = Liking::firstOrNew(array('post_id' => $id, 'ip' => Request::ip()));
            $liking->like = Input::get('liking') == 'like' ? 1 : 0;
            $liking->save();
```

Liking model code:

```
<?php

class Liking extends Eloquent{
    protected $table = 'post_liking';
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $timestamps = null;
    public $incremeting = false;
}
```

I'm tried to set over 25000 xdebug nesting level, but it doesn't help to me

Comment: Do you have some extra methods in yout Liking class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eloquent can get upset if there's not a primary key in your model. Try including an `id` column in `post_liking` (even if you don't use it), and remove the `protected $primaryKey = null;` and `public $incremeting = false;` lines from your `Liking` model.

(If you add the `id` column to your table manually, rather than in a `migration` using `$table->increments('id');`, make sure you set it to an `unsigned` integer.)